# BatchUpdate Rows in Google Sheets using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, google-sheets-api

Im having trouble updating rows in Google Sheets using VB.Net. 
This is my code:

```
Dim service = New SheetsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential, .ApplicationName = ApplicationName})
        Dim spreadsheetId As String = "1mW-ndDolz_uECCMmAmKZ-sANoM9H53eqc231g98I06U"
        Dim spreadsheet As Spreadsheet = Nothing
        Dim content As BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest = New BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
        Dim request As Request = New Request()
        Dim deleteDimensionRequest As DeleteDimensionRequest = New DeleteDimensionRequest()
        Dim dimensionRange As DimensionRange = New DimensionRange()

        dimensionRange.Dimension = "A:B"
        dimensionRange.StartIndex = 0
        dimensionRange.EndIndex = 3
        dimensionRange.SheetId = 0
        deleteDimensionRequest.Range = dimensionRange

        Dim requests As IList(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)()
        requests.Add(request)
        content.Requests = requests
        Try
            service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(content, spreadsheetId)
        Catch e As IOException
            MsgBox(e.Message)
        End Try
```

It shows me an Error saying

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Request]'.

What Am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how VB.NET works, but based on your sample code and the error message, I would assume the problem is this line:

`Dim requests As IList(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)()`

It should probably be:

`Dim requests As IList(Of Request) = New List(Of Request)()`

Answer (score 0):

I am sure its working but I don't know its drawbacks

```
     Dim requests As IList(Of Request) 
     dim Req1 as List(Of Request) = new List(Of Request) 
    Req1.Add(request) 
    Requests = Req1.ToList()

 content.Requests = requests
```